# IRSTLM path environment variable

Tags: command-line, language-support, paths

I am trying to get IRSTLM to work.
I have set the pah using:

```
PATH=:/usr/local/lib/irstlm:$IRSTLM
```

And then when I am tyring to run the `build-lm.sh` function it is telling me that it is located in `/usr/local/bin`.

However if I change the path to this folder, it is telling me

`set IRSTLM environment variable with path to irstlm`

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Does `$IRSTLM` have a value?  If not, that's the problem you're having.  And it's not asking you to set the `$PATH`, it's asking you to set `$IRSTLM` to the full path to the executable/library

Comment: How would I go about doing that then ? And how does it differ to what I have already tried to come up with ? I feel I'm lacking knowledge here ^^

Comment: Linux/Unix is case sensitive, so you must assign to `PATH`, not `Path`.

Comment: I was actually using PATH but failed to transcribe it propery here, thanks for the catch ! I will change it in the main post